# Sharepoint 2013 WCF best practice?

Tags: c#, wcf, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I want to access to external database but without BCS, I have created a webservice and it's work fine with javascript and json. My quetion is, how can I use this WCF trought C#?

I have to add a config file and I don't know which endpoint I have to use SOAP, Basichttp....

Any one have a tutorial or some help what's the best practice with WCF for sharepoint 2013?

thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a service reference in the project to reference your WCF service: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb628652.aspx

You can then access the WCF service via code.  Make sure you close the connection when you are done accessing the service, use try/catch/finally as using blocks won't work correctly if the service goes into an error state (if I remember correctly).

Comment: My question is best practice not how to access via reference... my service don't have config file and no endpoint is defined... but it's work with javascript but via c# I have to pass authentication ... anyway thank you